# How do I use Desmodder intellisense autocomplete?

Tags: autocomplete, intellisense, desmos

When I try to use desmodder autocomplete, either by pressing enter, tab or arrow keys, it simply jumps me to a new line, or the end of the expression.

The only way to accept suggestions it to click them with the mouse. However, on the desmodder [website](https://www.desmodder.com/intellisense/) it says enter works. How do I fix this?